# Hadoop Hcatalog -How to pass key value pair

Tags: hadoop, hcatalog

I have a create table script where the table name will be decided at runtime. How do I pass the value to sql script?

I'm trying something like this

```
hcat -e "create table ${D:TAB_NAME} (name string)" -DTAB_NAME=person
```

But I keep getting errors.
Can I get the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
hcat -e 'create table ${hiveconf:TAB_NAME} (name string);' -DTAB_NAME=person2
```

Here are two things to note:

1. In shell, default variable expansion is `$` so your `${D:TAB_NAME}` is getting expanded to nothing before even getting passed to hcat parser. So, either escape the `$` or use strong quoting using: `''`.
2. Use `hiveconf` instead of `D` for variable substitution as hcat under the hoods is still using hive to parse commands.